# Slow reboot and logout in gnome3, normal from terminal

Tags: 12.10, gnome, logout

My Ubuntu 12.10 Computer running Gnome shell rather than unity, is now very slow to logout or reboot from desktop. It reverts to generic Ubuntu icon theme, and the screen goes dim. Programs can still be opened from Docky, but Gnome Shell is unresponsive. After 30 sec to 1 min, it will logout or reboot without warning. There is apparently nothing taking up the system. When I run `sudo reboot` from the terminal, it just does it, with none of this dillydallying.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer - the spotify client wasn't logging out, causing a timeout. Manually closing spotify solved the problem.